# Problem with broken backup and python script

Tags: python

Right up front to be clear, I am not fluent in programming or python, but generally can accomplish what I need to with some research. Please excuse any bad formatting structure, as this is my first post to a board like this

I recently updated my laptop from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. I created a full system backup with Dejadup, which due to a missing file, could not be restored. Research brought me to post on here from 2019 for manually restoring these files. The process called for 2 scripts, 1 to unpack and the second to reconstruct the files, both created by Hamish Downer.

The first,

```
"for f in duplicity-full.*.difftar.gz; do echo "$f"; tar xf "$f"; done"
```

seemed to work well and did unpack the files.

The second,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3    
import argparse
from pathlib import Path
import shutil
import sys"
```

is the start of a re-constructor script. Using terminal from within the directory I am trying to rebuild I enter the first line and return.
When I enter the second line of code the terminal just "hangs" with no activity, and will only come back to the prompt if I double click the cursor. I receive no errors or warnings. When I enter the third line of code

```
"from pathlib import Path"
```

and return I then get an error

```
from: can't read /var/mail/pathlib
```

The problem seems to originate with the "import argparse" command and I assume is due to a symlink.

argparse is located in  /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (1.4.0)
python3 is located in   /usr/bin/

Python came with the Ubuntu 20.04 distribution package.

Any help with reconstructing these files would be greatly appreciated, especially in a batch as this script is meant to do versus trying to do them one file at a time.

Update: I have tried adding the "re-constructor" part of this script without success. This is a link to the script I want to use:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1123058/extract-unencrypted-duplicity-backup-when-all-sigtar-and-most-manifest-files-are

Re-constructor script:

```
class FileReconstructor():

def __init__(self, unpacked_dir, restore_dir):
    self.unpacked_path = Path(unpacked_dir).resolve()
    self.restore_path = Path(restore_dir).resolve()

def reconstruct_files(self):
    for leaf_dir in self.walk_unpacked_leaf_dirs():
        target_path = self.target_path(leaf_dir)
        target_path.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        with target_path.open('wb') as target_file:
            self.copy_file_parts_to(target_file, leaf_dir)

def copy_file_parts_to(self, target_file, leaf_dir):
    file_parts = sorted(leaf_dir.iterdir(), key=lambda x: int(x.name))
    for file_part in file_parts:
        with file_part.open('rb') as source_file:
            shutil.copyfileobj(source_file, target_file)

def walk_unpacked_leaf_dirs(self):
    """
    based on the assumption that all leaf files are named as numbers
    """
    seen_dirs = set()
    for path in self.unpacked_path.rglob('*'):
        if path.is_file():
            if path.parent not in seen_dirs:
                seen_dirs.add(path.parent)
                yield path.parent

def target_path(self, leaf_dir_path):
    return self.restore_path / leaf_dir_path.relative_to(self.unpacked_path)

def parse_args(argv):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        'unpacked_dir',
        help='The directory with the unpacked tar files',
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        'restore_dir',
        help='The directory to restore files into',
    )
    return parser.parse_args(argv)


def main(argv):
    args = parse_args(argv)
    reconstuctor = FileReconstructor(args.media/jerry/ubuntu, args.media/jerry/Restored)
    return reconstuctor.reconstruct_files()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
```

Comment: can you substitute the first line with #!/usr/bin/python and give it another shot?

Comment: Please provide the full error message, including the traceback.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response!! I have tried using "python" vs "python3 with the same result.

Comment: All of the code for the "re-constructor script" should be entered in a file, and that file executed all at once.  You can't necessarily type in Python code line-by-line and have it work - there are additional rules about where blank lines can appear when Python is used that way (nothing like that appears in the fragment you posted, but it's quite likely to be a problem somewhere within the entire script).

Comment: Thank you for your response! As I understand it, the 5 lines of code that I listed would be input one at a time in terminal to "start" the python program, and the balance of the "re-constructor" code would be entered as a single input run the script. Or do I have to Input all of the script at one time? I will edit my original post with the complete "re-constructor' script for better clarity

Answer (score 0):

I think you are typing the commands to the shell instead of python interpreter. Please check your prompt, python (started with python3) has `>>>`.

Linux has an `import` command (part of the ImageMagick) and understands `import argparse`, but it does *something completely different*.

> import - saves any visible window on an X server and outputs it as an
> image file. You can capture a single window, the entire screen, or any
> rectangular portion of the screen.

This matches the described behaviour. `import` waits for a mouse click and then creates a large output file. Check if there is a new file named `argparse`.

---

An executable script contains instruction to be processed by an interpreter and there are many possible interpreters, several shells (bash and alternatives), languages like Perl, Python, etc. and also some very specialized like `nft` for firewall rules.

If you execute a script from the command line, the shell reads its first line. If it starts with `#!` characters (called "shebang"), it uses the program listed on that line. (note: /usr/bin/env there is just a helper to find the exact location of a program).

But if you want to use an interpreter interactively, you need to start it explicitly. The shebang line has no special meaning in this situation, only as the very first line of a script. Otherwise it is just a comment and is ignored.

Comment: Upon review I believe you are correct, that I am in fact attempting to execute the commands in shell versus interpreter. There is a new file named argparse in the directory.  Being an absolute newbie, how do I start this script in terminal and then reconstruct the files in a specific directory? I can include the balance of the re-construction script if needed

Comment: @JerrySwensen I have expanded my answer.

Comment: So, I am making progress on this project. I was able to get into python on the terminal and enter all of the script correctly. When I ran the "re-constructor" it returned an error:

Comment: I got IDLE setup and the script copy pasted into it, took few edits and shell runs to get everything back to its correct format as it was posted.Last run came back with:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
    class FileReconstructor():
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 54, in FileReconstructor
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 48, in main
    args = parse_args(argv)
NameError: name 'parse_args' is not defined. Getting closer, but need to resolve these conflicts. I am going to try to edit my original post with the script.

Comment: @JerrySwensen please post a separate question for the second problem (read the StackOverflow rules). A new posting will get more attention.